# Why hasn't html a simple way of showing html tags as they are?

Tags: comments

html comments meant to be read by the person reading the source are like `<!-- Write your comments here -->`
But sometimes we want to depict a html as it is, for example show `<b>` to the end user and do not interpret the elemnt. Why the need to express this as `<pre>&lt;b&gt;</pre>` ? Why not a less convoluted way of doing this?

Comment: I don't understand what this question is asking. Do you want to know why HTML uses character entity escapes as opposed to something else, or why it uses escapes at all, or are you asking for alternatives?

Comment: @Ginger I think they're asking why there isn't some sort of tag for quoting and displaying raw HTML

Comment: I think the answer is essentially: There isn't much desire for it. It's not often that someone is writing HTML by hand *and* wants a lot of HTML tags displayed. Most HTML is generated, which prevents this from even being much of an inconvenience. This is what I would recommend: Generate your HTML. Then you can have a function that will replace `<` with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt;` which you can use whenever you want to display HTML tags in the result.

Comment: You can do this with `<xmp>`, but it's deprecated.

Comment: Most HTML is generated nowadays, but when the language was being designed in the first place it was almost all written by hand. But also, when the language was being designed in the first place, it wasn't designed for ease of presenting code.

Comment: Are you looking for the deprecated [<plaintext> tag](https://www.w3docs.com/learn-html/html-plaintext-tag.html)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on a false premise ─ HTML does have multiple ways to achieve this, so there is no design rationale needed for why it doesn't.

Comment: That isn't correct, though; `<xmp>` is long-deprecated & removed from the specification (and *why* would make a good component of an answer); contra the current top answer, CDATA sections have never been supported in text/html; plain-text scripts displayed inline are a hack for a Stack Overflow answer, not a design rationale answer for here; any contrast between the parsing requirements for `<xmp>` (gone) and `<script>` (present) would also support an answer.

Comment: Doesn't HTML DOM have a text node system?

Answer (score 3):

Posting this as a community wiki since it's not really an answer.

You can abuse a `<script>` or `<style>` tag to get the effect you require:

```
<script style="display: inline" type="text/plain">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
</script>
```

Renders literally `<h1>Hello</h1>` and does not interpret any HTML in the middle. This uses entirely modern HTML and is up to date with recent standards, though that does not make this less of a terrible hack.

If the text contains the literal text `</script>` anywhere it will break out though so be careful inserting any untrusted strings, or you will have a nasty XSS vulnerability.

Tested in most modern browsers.

Use with caution.

Answer (score 2):

HTML actually does support what you want, via the [`xmp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/xmp) tag:

```html
<xmp>John Smith <foo bar baz /></xmp>
```

However, `xmp` is deprecated, has inconsistent implementation across browsers, and may be removed in future versions. Considering HTML [goes to great lengths to preserve backwards-compatibility (quirks mode)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Quirks_Mode_and_Standards_Mode), you can *probably* get away with it and your site will work on the major browsers for a long time (though any parsing library will probably fail unless it's especially compliant); but if at all possible, you should just escape the text and use `<pre>` instead.

## Why isn't it (officially, reliably) supported?

HTML is very old, and the original format (arguably) had many oversights including this.

To change HTML to support unescaped text today, we'd have to get all major browsers to agree to a standard. Doing so will make outdated browsers fail to parse the new strings/delimiters, and outdated websites may break if they accidentally encode them. Browser maintainers don't like breaking outdated versions and websites, as evidenced by backwards-compatible quirks like the aptly-named ["quirks mode"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Quirks_Mode_and_Standards_Mode).

Furthermore, as David Young mentioned, there isn't much desire. You can already represent the text simply by escaping it, and most people aren't writing HTML by hand anyways, they're using HTML generators and template engines which escape the text for you.

So the simple reason is, **the original designers of HTML must have overlooked or not cared about unescaped text, and once HTML became mainstream, there's never been enough movement to make the huge changes necessary.**

## How could it be supported

### Via `CDATA`

[`CDATA`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) part of [XML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XML/XML_introduction). It may even work if you make your webpage into [XHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/XHTML), which is basically HTML modified to be valid XML. However, like `xmp`, XHTML is also deprecated and [attempts at modernizing it abandoned](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/149843).

```xml
<![CDATA[John Smith <foo bar baz />]]>
```

### Via [here strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document)

Another way that HTML could represent truly unescaped text, is using here strings. Here strings let you specify an arbitrary close delimiter, so technically, any possible text can be unescaped within the string and it will not break out; `xmp` can't encode `</xmp>`, and `CDATA` can't encode `]]>`, because those are the closing delimiters.

**Example 1:**

```
<<END
Foo bar "baz"
qux
END
```

Unquotes to

```
Foo bar "baz"
qux
```

**Example 2** (string containing "END"):

```
<<END2
Foo
END
END2
```

Unquotes to

```
Foo
END
```

**Example 3** (string containing "END" and "END2"):

```
<<END3
END END2
Foo
END3
```

Unquotes to

```
END END2
Foo
```

and so on.

Comment: I think this would answer the question more if it touched on *why* `<xmp>` was deprecated - that would directly answer it as asked. I am inclined to think everything about heredocs is not relevant, but noting that XHTML supported `<![CDATA[` blocks would help in that section too.

Comment: I don't think `<![CDATA[ ... ]]>` *is* supported in HTML in any current browser; it will just be discarded as an invalid tag that wasn't understood.